# audio_service Plugin: AudioService.connected return False

Tags: flutter

After init AudioService and play audio successfully, but I "lost" the AudioService connection, and the pause or play and the `AudioService.playbackStateStream` not update.

My AudioService.start is call on initState:

```
  initPlaying() async {
    AudioService.start(
      backgroundTaskEntrypoint: _audioPlayerTaskEntrypoint,
      androidNotificationChannelName: 'Audio Service Demo',
      androidNotificationColor: 0xFF2196f3,
      androidNotificationIcon: 'mipmap/ic_launcher',
    );
  }
```

After that, in debugger, the result of AudioService.connected is False.

This is my `CustomAudioPlayer` class:

```
class CustomAudioPlayer extends BackgroundAudioTask {
  MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem(
      id: 'audio_1',
      album: 'Igreja em Aracaju',
      title: 'Jesus é Deus',
      artUri: 'https://tecnocamp.info/assets/noimageavailable.jpg');

  Future<void> audioStart() async {
    await FlutterRadio.audioStart();
  }

  @override
  onStart(Map<String, dynamic> params) async {
    AudioServiceBackground.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
    AudioServiceBackground.setState(
        controls: [pauseControl, stopControl],
        playing: true,
        processingState: AudioProcessingState.ready);
    await audioStart();
    onPlay();
  }

  @override
  void onPlay() {
    AudioServiceBackground.setState(
        controls: [pauseControl, stopControl],
        playing: true,
        processingState: AudioProcessingState.ready);
    FlutterRadio.play(url: streamUrl);
  }

  @override
  void onPause() {
    AudioServiceBackground.setState(
        controls: [playControl, stopControl],
        playing: false,
        processingState: AudioProcessingState.ready);
    FlutterRadio.pause(url: streamUrl);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> onStop() async {
    await FlutterRadio.stop();
    exit(0);
    await super.onStop();
    await AudioServiceBackground.setState(
        controls: [],
        playing: false,
        processingState: AudioProcessingState.stopped);
  }

  @override
  Future onCustomAction(_function, params) {
    AudioServiceBackground.setMediaItem(MediaItem(
        id: params['mediaID'],
        album: params['mediaAlbum'],
        title: params['mediaTitle'],
        artUri: params['mediaCover']));
  }
}
```

My Full app can view in: https://github.com/yagoliveira92/radio-basic/tree/develop/

Answer (score 0):

Response: I put the `initPlaying()` in the Screen with close seconds after. Put this method in `main()` resolve the problem.